# mysql - difference between two integer column doesn't works as expected

Tags: mysql

I'm run this query:

```
SELECT id,like - dislike as result
FROM mytable
```

Where the column like and dislike are unsigned integer. If the column dislike is greater than like mysql return number like 18446744073709551596, so seem that mysql treat this like unsigned and can't return negative number but continue the computation from a sort of MAX_UNSIGNED_INT. How can I have the correct result

Comment: Could you add the result of show create table mytable ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try casting the two values (or maybe only on of them)

```
SELECT id, convert(like, SIGNED ) - convert(dislike, SIGNED ) as result
FROM mytable
```

or only the result

```
SELECT id, convert(like - dislike, SIGNED ) as result
FROM mytable
```

In the first way you can get type overflow! The Second way is better, but I'm not sure it works with mysql.

Comment: i've just try something like CAST(like as UNSIGNED) - CAST(like as UNSIGNED) but doesn't work

Comment: cast as signed :). With CAST(like as UNSIGNED) you basically cast from UNSIGNED to UNSIGNED which is the same

Answer (score 1):

You could try casting them as Int:

```
SELECT id, CAST(like AS INT) - CAST(dislike AS INT) as result FROM mytable
```